# li.hover not changing color

Tags: html, css

Here is my html

```
    <div class="pure-u" id="menu" data-ng-controller="gotoUrl">
            <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open">
                <a class="pure-menu-heading"
                   href="#">PennyTracker</a>
                <ul>
                    <!-- Add Transaction Button -->
                    <li>
                        <button
                                class="pure-button pure-button-success pure-button-large"
                                data-ng-click="setRoute('new')">
                            <i class="icon-plus"></i>
                            Transaction
                        </button>
                    </li>
                  ......
     </div>
```

and here is the css I try to change the color when hover on `li`

```
.pure-menu li.hover {
    background: red;
    color: #000000;
}
```

But I see no red color when I hover, I see

[image]

What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: `hover` is not a class attribute... it is a pseudo class so instead of `.` you need to use `:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must put `:` instead of `.` ,hover is not a class.

```
.pure-menu li:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #000000;
}
```